# Are objects in a JAVA array exclusive?

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing code for a 220 class and which adds Songs which is handled by one class to another class called MixCD which has an array of songs. My question is that when defining the second or third SONG will it mess with the previous songs in the array or are they exclusive?

The code for adding a song is this

```
System.out.println("What is the Song Title?");
                songA.setTitle(sc.next());
                System.out.println("What is the Song's Artist?");
                songA.setArtist(sc.next());
                System.out.println("How long is the Song? (In Seconds)");
                songA.setRunTime(sc.nextInt());
                if(((songA.getRunTime() / 60) < songCD.calcRemainingTime())){
                    if (songCD.addToCD(songA) == true){
                        System.out.println("Song successfully added");
                        lastSongAdded = songA;          
                    } //if
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Song was unable to be added");
                    } //else
                } //if
                else {
                    System.out.println("Song was unable to be added");
                }
                break;

And the Add to CD code is this:
            for(int i = 0; i < mySongs.length; i++) {
            if( mySongs[i] != null ) {
                mySize++;
            }
        }
        if (mySize < (mySongs.length-1)){
            mySongs[mySize] = newSong;
            return true;
        } //if
        else {
            return false;
        } //else
    } //addToCD
```

So when adding new songs to a CD it changes songA but will it change the song in songCD[0] and so on?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your song object is mutable, and you keep reusing the same instance in all iterations of the loop.

You should find a place in the loop where you start defining the next song, and create a new song object at that point. Otherwise, multiple elements of the array point to the same object, creating a situation when changing one song leads to changes in all other songs stored in the array.

Here is an illustration of what you need to build (on the left) and what you have now (on the right).

[image: An illustration]

Here is how you do it with a `for` loop:

```
int numberOfSongs = ...; // Figure out how many songs there are
Song[] songs = new Song[numberOfSongs];
for (int i = 0 ; i != numberOfSongs ; i++) {
    songs[i] = new Song(); // create a new song
    song[i].setName(...);  // do the rest of song's processing
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sure, I see what you are saying, how would I build a FOR loop that would accomplish my issue? Is there a way to dynamically define variables?

Comment: @user2877402 Yes, with the `new` keyword.

Comment: @user2877402 An array can be thought of as a way to define variables dynamically. See my edit for a way to set up multiple songs in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

`songA` is not an object, it is a reference to an object.

So as long as you do something like the below, you are good

`songA = new Song()`

**You need this for each new song you want to add.**

If you do not have this, what you say will happen. All of the songs will be the same and they will all change

Comment: Could I redefine songA in the loop or would I have to create whole new SONG? Like each time I want to add a song could I say  songA = new Song(tempTitle, tempArtist, tempRunTime);  Or would I have to have a completely different SONG object each time?

Comment: @user2877402 both of those things mean the same

Comment: i.e `songA = new Song(tempTitle, tempArtist, tempRunTime);` is creating a new song object. Bear in mind the `new Song...` is the object and `songA` is only a reference to the object